# Printing Magento Page prints blank in the content area

Tags: magento-1.9, print

For one of our clients their customers need to be able to print out certain pages on the website. Whenever we try and print it will print out a page as it normally would putting the title tag / url at the top and time / number of pages at the bottom. However, the content area is blank.

Any ideas?

I've tried across all browsers and we have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds like a CSS issue, I suggest you look at this post to be able to view the print version of your page in your browser so you can inspect the content element and see if the content is not hidden by a CSS rule

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105147/see-print-css-in-the-browser

Comment: We've gone over all of the stylesheets and there are currently no print css styles applied to the site.

Comment: Did you manage to double check if the content element contained any data by viewing the print CSS view ?